# Exim filters, header variables and MIME encoding

Tags: exim

I write exim filters to forward e-mail (like maillist). In filter condition I use header variables. And I faced with some difficultes with $h_subject encoding. Try to explain with example.

New e-mail sent from gmail with subject of few russian words. Of course, subject header is MIME-encoded. It looks like this:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?[nr=5Fbill]=20=D0=9D=D0=BE=D0=B2=D1=8B=D0=B9=20?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=20=D0=BE=D1=84=D0=BE=D1=80=D0=BC=D0=BB=D0=B5=D0=BD?=
```

In Exim filter I want to use next condition: `$h_subject: contains "[nr_bill] Новый заказ оформлен"`

The problem is that Exim decodes only the first line of header. Decoded header looks like this:

```
[nr_bill] \320\235\320\276\320\262\321\213\320\271 \n =?utf-8?Q?=D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=20=D0=BE=D1=84=D0=BE=D1=80=D0=BC=D0=BB=D0=B5=D0=BD?=
```

The first line is successfully decoded and can be used in filters. But the second line is not decoded. And the worst: Exim saves spaces and newline carater beetween lines. As I know, new lines and leadind spaces in headers must be omitted in parsing time.

So `$h_subject: contains "[nr_bill] Новый` is working well, while `$h_subject: contains "[nr_bill] Новый заказ оформлен"` not.

[Manual](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/exim-doc-4.63/html/doc/filter.html#SECTheadervariables) says that newline+spaces is normal practice. But it says nothins about multipart MIME-decoding.

Can anyone propound how to resolve this problem or just explain what is the point of those behavior?

Comment: Exim is following RFC2047 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) literally. see section 6(1) - longer than 75 characters should be treated as ordinary ASCII text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found. Thanks to [Phil](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/exim/users/79643#79643) :)

> Exim is being very carefully adherent to the MIME specification in
> RFC2047 which places a maximum length on each encoded-word.
>
> ----------------------------8< cut here >8------------------------------
>
> encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
> [...]
>
> An 'encoded-word' may not be more than 75 characters long, including
> 'charset', 'encoding', 'encoded-text', and delimiters. If it is
> desirable to encode more text than will fit in an 'encoded-word' of
> 75 characters, multiple 'encoded-word's (separated by CRLF SPACE) may
> be used.
>
> ----------------------------8< cut here >8------------------------------
>
> So the MIME decoder is skipping those long strings and adding them
> literally.
>
> ...
>
> If you set "check_rfc2047_length" false in Exim's main configuration,
> the header will be decoded correctly; I would assume (but haven't
> checked) that Exim would then re-encode things correctly as needed.
>
> check_rfc2047_length = false

So after setting `check_rfc2047_length = false` all variations of problematic subjects are decoded correctly.

Comment: Although encoded words are limited to 75 characters, you are allowed to put multiple encoded words back to back, if you need to.

Comment: This worked for me to get proper Exim's Sieve filtering matching against encoded Subject.

Comment: by "correct" you mean "expected"  exim's default is correct according to section 6 of the RFC2047 document.